# Kohana CRUD: Undefined Variable

Tags: php, undefined, kohana, kohana-orm

PHP Function to select and display all the records stored under the column "clubName", from the table 'clubs'. The foreach statement ($club) returns an undefined variable error. What have I missed?

Controller:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

    class Club_Controller extends Template_Controller {
        public $template = 'kohana/template';
        public function index()
        {
            $this->template->title = 'All clubs';
            $this->template->content = new View('allclubs');
            $clubs = ORM::factory('club')->find_all();
            $this->template->content->club = $clubs;
        }   
    }
?>
```

View:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.'); ?>
<div class="box">
    <b><?php echo html::anchor('entry/form', 'add entry') ?></b><br>
    <table cellpadding="10">

        <?php foreach($clubs as $club): ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
            <?php echo html::anchor('entry/form/'.$club->id, 'edit') ?>
            <?php echo html::anchor('entry/delete/'.$club->id, 'delete',
                             array('onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you realy realy want to do it?")')) ?>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            <?php echo $club->clubName ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
$this->template->content->club = $clubs;
```

to this

```
$this->template->content->clubs = $clubs;
```